# Defining a fallback route

Tags: aurelia

How can I define a fallback route in Aurelia which is navigated to when the current URL does not match any of routes in the configuration?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the docs [here](http://aurelia.io/docs/routing/configuration#configuring-a-fallback-route) you can use

```
config.mapUnknownRoutes('not-found');
```

which will redirect any unmapped routes to the not-found component.

Comment: How to do the same in Aurelia 2 ?